# tslint rule for prevent only method of chai

Tags: chai, eslint, tslint

I use `chai` for unit tests. But often forget remove `only`method before `commit`. It will be nice to have `tslint` rule for it.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[tslint-microsoft-contrib](https://github.com/Microsoft/tslint-microsoft-contrib) has a `mocha-avoid-only` rule that should be exactly what you need.

By the way, a hint for searching: Chai is the library that has a bunch of assertions (methods that throw an error if something is wrong). You're likely using a different library to set up your tests, likely Mocha.